Effects no longer work with reactive objects when using runes
In Svelte 4, the effect below would fire every time user or pass props from it changed
let data = {
    user,
    pass,
};

$: data && clearErrors()

In Svelte 5 the equivalent code with runes would be:
let data = $state({
    user: '',
    pass: ''
})

$effect(() => data && clearErrors());

But now the effect does not run when user or pass props are changed. Can someone explain to me why this happens?

This code is not equivalent, which is why the migration script will turn it into: run(() => { data && clearErrors() });

In Svelte 5 reactivity is fine-grained:
If you reference just data, only a re-assignment of data itself will trigger the $effect.
Either reference the properties individually, or if you really want to trigger on everything inside the object, use something like $state.snapshot to make sure all properties are evaluated.

thanks. solved it with (data.user || data.pass) && clearErrors()

Note that logical operator abuse is generally a bad idea. If data.user is truthy, the statement will short-circuit and data.pass will not become a dependency of the effect. Not sure if this is the intended behavior here.
